# How to skip the words not in the dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a file as a dictionary word:

```
water=45 
melon=8 
apple=35 
pineapple=67 
I=43 
to=90 
eat=12 
tastes=100 
sweet=21 
it=80 
watermelon=98 
want=70
juice=88
```

and I have another file with the following text:

```
I want to eat banana and watermelon 
I want drink juice purple and pineapple
```

I want to output :

```
43, 70, 90, 12, 98
43, 70, 88, 67
```

every word that does not exist in the dictionary are in skip.

This is what I have so far:

```
import re
f = open(r'C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop\val.txt','r')
val_dict = {}
for line in f:
     k, v = line.strip().split('=')
     val_dict[k.strip()] = v.strip()
f.close()


h = open(r'C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop\str_txt.txt','r')
str_list = []
for line in h:
     str_list.append(str(line).strip())



tmp_str = ''
for val in str_list:
    tmp_str = val 
    for k in val_dict.keys():
            if k in val:
                replace_str = str(val_dict[k]).strip() + ","
                tmp_str= re.sub(r'\b{0}\b'.format(k),replace_str,tmp_str,flags=re.IGNORECASE)

    tmp_str = tmp_str.strip(",")
    print val, " = ", tmp_str
    tmp_str = ''
```

Output :

```
43, 70, 90, 12, banana and 98
43, 70, drink 88, purple and 67
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we can parse your "dictionary file" into an actual Python dictionary using a clever `dict` comprehension.

```
In [1]: dict_file = """water=45 
   ...: melon=8 
   ...: apple=35 
   ...: pineapple=67 
   ...: I=43 
   ...: to=90 
   ...: eat=12 
   ...: tastes=100 
   ...: sweet=21 
   ...: it=80 
   ...: watermelon=98 
   ...: want=70
   ...: juice=88"""

In [2]: conversion = {k: int(v) for line in dict_file.split('\n') for (k,v) in (line.split('='),)}

In [3]: conversion
Out[3]: 
{'I': 43,
 'apple': 35,
 'eat': 12,
 'it': 80,
 'juice': 88,
 'melon': 8,
 'pineapple': 67,
 'sweet': 21,
 'tastes': 100,
 'to': 90,
 'want': 70,
 'water': 45,
 'watermelon': 98}
```

We then set the phrase to a variable.

```
In [4]: text = "I want to eat banana and watermelon"
```

We can use `str.split` to change the single string into a list of the words.

```
In [5]: text.split()
Out[5]: ['I', 'want', 'to', 'eat', 'banana', 'and', 'watermelon']
```

To check if each word is in the `conversion` dictionary, we can simply use the `in` keyword, which checks dictionary keys.

```
In [6]: "banana" in conversion
Out[6]: False

In [7]: "watermelon" in conversion
Out[7]: True
```

We can implement this in a list comprehension to filter only the words that our conversion dictionary knows how to convert to a number. We can also look for the value `conversion[word]`, which we know exists because we already confirmed that the comprehension only looks at values which are in the conversion `dict`.

```
In [9]: [str(conversion[word]) for word in text.split() if word in conversion]
Out[9]: ['43', '70', '90', '12', '98']
```

Finally, we can use `str.join` to combine this list back into a single string. (The square brackets are removed, which makes the expression a *generator* comprehension, not a list comprehension, but it works either way.)

```
In [10]: ', '.join(str(conversion[word]) for word in text.split() if word in conversion)
Out[10]: '43, 70, 90, 12, 98'
```

Success! You can apply this method to any of the phrases in your file via a simple `for` loop to get the desired result.

There isn't much of a need for regex here; Python's string processing features are very powerful. :)

Comment: I've tried to run the code, but the output is not in performing ..., this is his code [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMZDI2MDhaV2FZZFE)

Comment: @RiskaNanda You copied the `...:`'s that IPython generated; if you remove them, it works. :)

Comment: I have deleted it but the results remain the same.[link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMczl4VXJXTDVYa0U)

Comment: @RiskaNanda You left whitespace before each item (12 spaces) - the items should all be aligned with the first column, with no whitespace beforehand.

Comment: I get ValueError: too many values to unpack at line `conversion = {k: int(v) for line in dict_file.split('\n') for (k,v) in (line.split('='),)}`

Comment: @RiskaNanda Try copying the code [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/MQJXEhj3) directly. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.get` which allows for a default value if you don't find the key.

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> d['c']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'c'

>>> d.get('c', 'fallback value')
'fallback value'
```

This will let you do something like:

```
nums = [dict.get(val, '') for val in str_list]
# [43, 70, 90, 12, '', '', 98]
```

Then remove the empty strings with `filter`

```
nums = filter(None, nums)
# with `None` as the first argument, this removes all elements that eval to False
```

Then map to string and join with commas

```
print(", ".join(map(str, nums)))
```

Comment: I have error :TypeError: descriptor 'get' requires a 'dict' object but received a 'str', This is not the default dictionary python, I make a dictionary manually in a text file.

Comment: @RiskaNanda my code assumes you've already processed the text file into a dictionary, as you had already done in your own code. I can produce a complete example if necessary.

Comment: I am still a little confused how to apply it. Can you produce a complete example?

Comment: @RiskaNanda https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/a3d3e3798e652259480cbeaeb94dd6b4

Comment: I get an error : TypeError: filter expected 2 arguments, got 1

Comment: @RiskaNanda my fault, you need to pass `None` as the second argument to `filter`.

Comment: I get an error : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @RiskaNanda *grumble* apparently it's been much too long since I've used map/filter/reduce stuff in Python. `None` should be the FIRST argument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136185/discussion-between-adam-smith-and-riska-nanda).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using `list comprehension` in order to have your desired output:

I'm assuming your dictionary file is called `file1` and your second file is called `file2`.

```
data1 = [k.rstrip().split("=") for k in open("file1", 'r')]
data2 = [k.rstrip().split() for k in open("file2", 'r')]

for k in data2:
    for j in k:
        for m in data1:
            if j == m[0]:
                print(m[1], end = ' ')
    print()
```

Output:

```
43 70 90 12 98 
43 70 88 67
```

Comment: I want to output the appropriate sentence in file2.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You could have the exact desired output.